# Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero

Tags: php, php7

Buenas lo que trató de hacer es calcular el desempeño que hay dependiendo de las ventas y las visitas por lo cual hago lo siguiente: `$total_rendimiento = (floatval($total_venta)/floatval($total_visitas));` pero al hacer esto me dice que hay un error el cual es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero

los números que estoy usando son **$total_venta = 10** y  **$total_visitas = 18** lo cual me da 0.555 pero luego de eso lo voy a multiplicar por 100, pero el error sigue ahí y estropea mi algunas funcionalidades extra de la pagina ¿Cómo puedo hacer uso de esos 0.555 sin que php detecte que son 0?

Comment: En alguna parte de has cargado el `$total_visitas` antes de llegar a esa asignación y por eso tienes el error. Lo he probado tal cual lo has puesto y me da bien: `0.55555555555556`.  Fuérzalo un linea antes de esa operación y verás que funciona y no da error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

> Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero

**indica que se esta provocando una excepción aritmetica ya que estas dividiendo entre 0**, esto ocurre cuando el valor de `$total_visitas` tiene el valor de 0, en este caso puedes realizar una validación:

```
if ($total_visitas > 0) {
    $total_rendimiento = (floatval($total_venta)/floatval($total_visitas)); 
}else{
    $total_rendimiento = 0; //Valor predeterminado        
}
```

de esta forma cuando el valor de `$total_visitas` sea 0, el valor resultante de `$total_rendimiento` será simplemente 0.